# stopwords and phrase queries solr

Tags: solr

I using Solr **version 7.4** and `StopFilterFactory` and I want stopwords excluded except when the search term is within double quotes.

for example when I search `"to be or not to be"` will not retrieve any documents.

I know that in the **older version** I can use ‍`enablePositionIncrements="true"` but it deprecates now.

my `managed-schema` file.

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" multiValued="false">
    <analyzer type="index">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
      <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
      <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
      <filter class="solr.SynonymGraphFilterFactory" expand="true" ignoreCase="true" synonyms="synonyms.txt"/>
      <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you may need to have 2 separate fields.

Define field1 with a field type which has stopwordfilterfactory in the defination.

Define field2 with a field type without StopFilterFactory in the defination.

Search will happens on 1st field when you will not search request without the double quotes.

Seach will executes on 2nd field field2 when you will have search request with double quotes.

Comment: how to Search will happens on the `1st field` or `2nd field`? by coding or use Apache Solr config?

Comment: you have to decide it by coding...you have to determine that which field should be used depending on if you got the double quote or not